# Detecting if the application is in design mode in Windows Phone 7 ViewModel

Tags: windows-phone-7

Is there any way I can detect the designer mode or runtime mode of an WP7 project? Currently I reference Application.Current... in a ViewModel and apparently the View does not like it in designer. The XAML designer throws exception. It works fine in runtime. So I am thinking I can do some if/else in ViewModel to workaround this if I know it's in designer mode.

Thanks!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Simple. This is the same as it is in Silverlight:

```
DesignerProperties.IsInDesignTool
```

Answer (score 6):

You mean something like [DesignerProperties.IsInDesignTool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.designerproperties.isindesigntool%28VS.95%29.aspx)?